# Why does the gnome-control-center say that I am running 16.04 when I am running 15.10?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, versions, gnome-control-center, 16.04

I am running Ubuntu GNOME **15.10** with GNOME 3.18, however when going into the `Details` section of the `gnome-control-center` it tells me just under the logo that I am running `16.04`, though it then below says `Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit` (I have put a black box on the some of the information that I do not wish to be shown):

[image]

This is very strange, so I am wondering why this is the case? I am not running 16.04, so why does it say that I am?

**Information Update:**

The output of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

And the output of `apt-cache policy base-files gnome-shell` is:

```
base-files:
  Installed: 7.2ubuntu11
  Candidate: 7.2ubuntu11
  Version table:
 *** 7.2ubuntu11 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.18.2-0ubuntu2~wily1
  Candidate: 3.18.2-0ubuntu2~wily1
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.2-0ubuntu2~wily1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.16.4-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
     3.16.3-1ubuntu6+wily1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Odd that you didn't include `lsb_release` output as usual. What is the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy base-files`?

Comment: @muru: Sorry, I was going to, but then I just sort of got distracted and forgot... Anyway, I've updated it to include that information now.

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.16.4, NOREPRO. Sounds like a bug. Are you using GNOME from the GNOME repository?

Comment: @kos: I have installed GNOME 3.18 from the `gnome3` and `gnome3-staging` PPAs.

Comment: GNOME3 Staging is a testing branch. Reporting the description: "The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature.". So 99% that's a bug, or hardcoded as Fabby suggests below. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-shell`.

Comment: @kos: Ok, I have done so. **Question updated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.10 still comes with Gnome 3.16 by default.

GNOME 3.18 is the one that *will be released* (at the time of this writing) with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, and `gnome-control-center` is directly backported from 16.04 on the GNOME 3 Staging PPAs with the Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 logo [patched into it](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/gnome-control-center/ubuntu/view/head:/debian/patches/56_use_ubuntu_info_branding.patch#L23) at build time.

Comment: Actually, it comes with GNOME **3.16**. The odd numbered releases are the in-development versions, the even numbered releases are the stable releases.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda FWIW, on Arch Linux, which has pretty much vanilla packages, it displays the GNOME version there: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lXQDB.png - pretty clear it's been patched to display something else.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a GNOME version from the [GNOME3 Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging), which is a testing branch for the main [GNOME3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3).

Copying the relevant part from the description:

> This PPA will be used to test uploads before they are copied to the main GNOME 3 PPA.
>
> === *WARNING* ===
> The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature. Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge, when you encounter issues!

So unless the reported Ubuntu version is (at least currently) hard coded / by design as Fabby suggests that's due to an incomplete implementation / bug.